# Fluent NHibernate : Conventions / KeyColumn

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Below the code, a Customer can have several address. There is a one-to-many relation. I'd like in the Address table as FK a field named "Customer" and not "Customer_id"

I' tried to add : 
`.KeyColumn("Customer")` > no change

I tried to use to change ForeignKeyConvention no change.

Any idea ?

```
public class CustomerMap : ClassMap<Customer>
{
    protected CustomerMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Not.Nullable().Length(25);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        HasMany<Address>(x => x.Addresses)                
            .KeyColumn("Customer")
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class AddressMap : ClassMap<Address>
{
    public AddressMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.City).Not.Nullable().Length(100);
    }
}

public class ForeignKeyReferenceConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Key.PropertyRef("EntityId");
    }
}

public void DBCreation()
{
    FluentConfiguration config = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString("...."))
        .Mappings(m =>
            m.AutoMappings
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Customer>())
                .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Address>()
                    .Conventions.Setup(c => c.Add<ForeignKeyReferenceConvention>())
                    )
                );

    config.ExposeConfiguration(
              c => new SchemaExport(c).Execute(true, true, false))
         .BuildConfiguration();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used automapping myself, but isn't `ClassMap` only used with "default" fluent mapping (not automapping)? Do you want to use fluent mapping or auto mapping?

Why is your one-to-many inverse although you don't have a many-to-one side mapped?

Btw, what's the purpose of that convention? `PropertyRef()` shouldn't be used unless absolutely needed (NHibernate can't do some optimizations with that).

Comment: Your answer is more a comment than an answer. The purpose is match with a not new database.

Comment: @Kris-I Yeah, sorry, should have been a comment. Btw, I've edited my answer, you have most likely a problem with mixing fluent mapping and auto mapping.